# Webpack "error in ./src/main.js Syntax Error: "({\n new webpack.Def""

Tags: express, webpack, vue.js

I am following the Free Code Camp tutorial on [building a full stack web application with Express and Vue.js](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fa4cRMaTDUI&t=1803s). Upon launching the client server, I am running into this error:

[image: Error log]

The main.js looks like this:

```
// The Vue build version to load with the `import` command
// (runtime-only or standalone) has been set in webpack.base.conf with an 
alias.
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
el: '#app',
router,
template: '<App/>',
components: { App }
})
```

Deleting the content of this file still results in the same error, which might suggest the error originates in the Webpack configuration files.

The [entire project](https://github.com/wassbeer/expressappwithvuejs/tree/master/client) is available on Github.

Anybody experience with this error? Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used babel before, but this is what is causing your problem:

```
--- a/client/.babelrc
+++ b/client/.babelrc
@@ -5,10 +5,6 @@
     }],
     "stage-2"
   ],
-  "plugins":  ({
-  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
-            'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development')
-        }),
   "env": {
     "test": {
       "presets": ["env", "stage-2"],
```

Making the above change allowed me to run the local server.

It looks like maybe a global search & replace went awry because these are valid lines for webpack config files.